# How to change permission of /proc/self/pagemap file?

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo, chmod, chown

I want to change the pagemap file permission to 755 or 744 using sudo chmod. But the command is throwing error saying operation not permitted. The motivation is to allow a user read the pagemap file (of its own) without giving sudo access.

When the user have sudo access it is working, he allowed to read pagemap file. But I want to prevent the user to have sudo access, but should allow him to read this pagemap file alone.

Answer (score 2):

**The Linux kernel requires `sudo` for `/proc/<pid>/pagemap` since 4.0**

This is documented at:
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.9/Documentation/vm/pagemap.txt

```
   Since Linux 4.0 only users with the CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability can get PFNs.
   In 4.0 and 4.1 opens by unprivileged fail with -EPERM.  Starting from
   4.2 the PFN field is zeroed if the user does not have CAP_SYS_ADMIN.
   Reason: information about PFNs helps in exploiting Rowhammer vulnerability.
```

Where `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` basically means "run as `sudo`", or alternatively:

```
sudo setcap cap_sys_admin+ep program_that_uses_pagemap
./program_that_uses_pagemap
```

Keep in mind that [`/proc` is a virtual filesystem](https://superuser.com/questions/619955/how-does-proc-work/1442571#1442571), and so the Linux kernel can choose to enforce additional permissions or even alter results arbitrarily for non root as it does here for security reasons by setting PFNs to zero.

Comment: I think you should change that to "requires `CAP_SYS_ADMIN`" or "requires root-like privileges". *Nothing* requires "sudo", ever.

Comment: @mosvy thanks for suggestion, isn't basically that "basically means "run as sudo"" means? Doesn't sudo "give root for a command"? I'm not an expert, so maybe there is some further ambiguity I don't see, but this felt like a reasonable analogy for newbies, and `CAP_SYS_ADMIN ` is already mentioned too :-)

Comment: Newbies shouldn't even know that a thing called "sudo" ever existed. But don't take this too hard, I don't really care one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

you can try changing the permissions in the `/etc/init/mounted-proc.conf` file:

```
script
    chmod 0444 "${MOUNTPOINT}"/self/pagemap
end script
```

proc is a virtual filesystem generated by the kernel. If you can not change the permission it is not allowed by your kernel and you can only solve it by changing kernel.

Comment: This is absurd. `/proc/self` refers to the current process; your proposed script attempts to change the permission of the `pagemap` file in the `chmod` process just before that process exits. Even if it was possible, which it isn't, this wouldn't accomplish anything.